Knowing myself x Knowing me
In the sentence below, can either of the expressions "knowing myself" and "knowing me" be used?
Knowing myself the way I do, I know I would never last in a job like that for a long time.
Knowing me the way I do, I know I would never last in a job like that for a long time.
For me the most suitable seems to be "knowing myself" but both appear in a considerable number of results in searches I have done - although the largest number of results are for "knowing myself".

Knowing myself the way I do makes sense. So does Knowing me the way he does, ... Maybe that's what your search turned up.

While Knowing myself the way I do is the correct answer and Knowing me the way I do is technically incorrect, you will hear the latter in informal, spoken American English quite often.

One uses a reflexive pronoun when referring back to the subject.

"He gave himself a bruise."
"By itself, the car rolled downhill."
"We talked among ourselves."
"She was too modest about herself."
"Why don't you speak for yourself, John?"
"I celebrate myself, and sing myself."

BTW, an oddity of reflexive pronouns:

"Come yourself," would be a command to be there in person, not through a representative. ("You" is the understood subject.)
"Come by yourself," would be a command to come unaccompanied.

